# Comments On How JoeFlow Package Works

Tags: django, workflow

I've just started working with [JoeFlow](https://joeflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package and need some help on it.

I've installed it successfully and created an application based on [joeflow tutorial](https://joeflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/index.html).
But why workflows stop in second node i.e. 'has_user' with status 'scheduled'

How can I make workflows to proceed?

Any advice is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What's the problem with my question?

Comment: People around here are picky. Don't be discouraged. However, if you care to improve your future questions, please read the suggestions on the right of your screen, when creating a new question here. The best questions include a detailed description of your problem, describe your approaches to solving it, and include code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Joe here,

the author of joeflow. I presume your workflow come to a halt because you didn't set up an asynchronous task runner yet. You can choose between [Dramatiq](https://dramatiq.io/) or [Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/). You will find plenty of documentation on how to set up those packages together with Django.

Beware, that the learning curve for joeflow is much steeper if you have no prior experience with Django or Python.

BTW, I am not overly active on StackOverflow, you will however always find my on GitHub. Please don't hesitate to open questions in the Q&A section of our [discussion board](https://github.com/codingjoe/joeflow/discussions).

Best!
Joe